# Hide Formula Bar in specific worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

How to hide formula bar in a specific worksheet?

I try this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried above code but how to active formula bar when this worksheet will inactive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. Just make sure that your code is in the module for the worksheet you're working on. You will then see that it works fine.

Just add the following to get the formula bar back when the sheet is deactivated:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
End Sub
```